# Accessibility & Google Charts table hover behavior

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, accessibility, wai-aria

I've posted a couple of Google Charts accessibility questions already; here's one more. Thank you in advance for your help.

Google Charts tables are surprisingly easy to make accessible to blind users, but I'm running into a perplexing problem. I'm making a website that uses standard Google category filters to produce a data table. I've added `ARIA-live=polite` and `ARIA-atomic=true` attributes to the table to signal screen readers to read out the entire table when it changes. This works perfectly most of the time; when a control is changed, after reading out the control behavior the screen readers will immediately start reading the new table.

Unfortunately, changes in `class` attributes trigger ARIA-live. For Google Charts tables also tagged with ARIA-atomic, this means that *row hover behavior* will trigger a reading of the entire table, because hovering over a row changes the row class. And if you move the mouse pointer over more than one row, it'll read out the entire table once for every row over which you pass.

***EDIT: see NOTE below to clarify this paragraph.*** I've tried addressing this by tweaking the table's `cssClassNames` options, but the results are frankly maddening. Even when changing the `tableRow` and `hoverTableRow` options to the same class, the table will only apply that class when hovering, changing the class to `" "` when not hovering.

I've tried convincing my co-workers that users of screen readers won't be using mice, but I've been asked to find a solution anyway. Guh.

Does anyone understand how this row hover behavior works, exactly? Is the problem as inscrutable as I'm making it out to be, or am I missing something? Does anyone have any ideas for a workaround?

**NOTE:** Ryan B has a good workaround idea (see comment below), and that's exactly the kind of solution I'll propose if my co-workers insist that the current setup doesn't meet their standards. Thank you Ryan.

Still, in the hope that the problem is with my explanation, I'll clarify: when you hover over a row in a Google charts table, the background color changes. The Google Viz script manages this by listening for hover events over table rows. On hover, the script changes the row class name from something like `"tr-goo-viz-table-row"` to `"tr-goo-viz-table-row-over"`, both of which are in the Google Viz CSS and only include styles of background colors (white and light grey, respectively).

In the HTML table call one can set the `cssClassName` option for `hoverTableRow` to `"tr-goo-viz-table-row"` (or set both `tableRow` and `hoverTableRow` to any class that only sets the background color) and visually, the hover behavior stops. But in an odd quirk, the script insists on differentiating the class names on hover even if you're telling it to keep the class names the same. Depending on the implementation the script will produce a doubled class name (`"tr-goo-viz-table-row tr-goo-viz-table-row"`) for hover rows, or an empty class name (`""`) for non-hover rows, and either way that'll still trigger ARIA-live even though no style change is implemented and hovering has no visual effect.

Since I don't understand the implementation of this behavior, I'm hoping someone who understands it better than I do might know of a way to stop the hover-triggered class name changes altogether - killing the listener, etc. Something like adding "pointer-events:none" in the row CSS for example...except pointer-events wasn't supported in IE before IE11 and the people using this website will mostly be using IE9.

Comment: I don't quite follow the hovering part. One thing you may be able to do is drop `aria-live` and `atomic` on the table. Add a line above the table, ideally a caption, with  those ARIA properties with text like *"the results have been updated"*, or whatever is applicable to your project.